# How to use screens and add additional paths for the web version in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm still figuring out what is the best way to combine `React Native` with current web standards. But I came to a point where using `React Web` over `React Native` is more complicated compared to the other way around.

So I noticed that a proper way for me could be using `React Stack Screens`. This works well in Native and Web and looks the same way.

But unfortunately this is not enough for me on the Web version. I would like to have the usual path based version of the screens. E.g. `/new` or `/search` and so on.

This is how I create my screens:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="home"
      component={Home}
      options={{ title: 'ProjectName' }}
    />
    ...
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Now how can I use those screens and add the additional paths for the web version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [React docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#linking), all that needs to be done is adding the `deep linking` to the `NavigationContainer`:

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      {/* content */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

And for the `linking` part you need to define your overwrites before that. Do this with:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['http://localhost:19006', 'project://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Home: 'home',
      Search: 'search',
      Login: 'login',
    },
  },
};
```

Find more info [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links).